# PHP - Finding words in HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

Looking for the best way to get the content of some HTML text in some random pieces of HTML

I cannot seem to figure out the regex for it.

```
<td valign="top" style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 4px;">
    <h4>Dec 05, 2015 23:16:52</h4>
    <h3>rron7pam has won</h3>
</td>

<table width="100%" style="border: 1px solid #DED3B9" id="attack_info_att">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:20%">Attacker:</th>
            <th><a title="..." href="/guest.php?screen=info_player&amp;id=255995">Bliksem</a></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above are only examples, but for these examples, I am interested in

- Getting the date (date = Dec 05, 2015 23:16:52)
- Who won the battle (name = rron7pam)
- The name of the attacker (name = Bliksem)
- Attacker's ID (id = 255995)

There are lots more information that I need from separate HTML code pieces, but if I can get one or two right, I might be able to get some more.

**EDIT based on comments and answers:** 
There could be any arbitrary text in the HTML, depending on how the report was set up (to hide attacker's units, etc.) I need to look for patterns of specific HTML tags

In the example above, "The text between the `<h4></h4>` tags directly following a set of `<h3></h3>` tags inside a `<td>`" will be the date that I need.

Some examples of links with different formats:

https://enp2.tribalwars.net/public_report/70d3a2a55461e9eb09f543958b608304
https://enp2.tribalwars.net/public_report/5216e0e16c9d3657f981ce7e3cb02580

There are elements that will always be the same, as far as I can tell, e.g., as per the above to get the date.

Comment: you can consider using XPath for your task

Comment: Check out the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument) class.

Comment: Hi Terminus. Not sure how DOMDocument will help me? I am provided with the HTML, I do not need to create it. Seems DOMDocument is to create the HTML/XML?

Comment: pavlovich, thanks - again the document fragments I will get are not valid XML paths, but custom HTML with tables, and inline styles, and every other thing you can think of (probably would be valid HTML, I am sure - this is the HTML output from a major online game's report).

Comment: but XPath works with HTML very well, http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php. You can load it and then parse with XPath queries

Comment: DOMDocument can be used to search through html. There are many ways it can do this. Xpath is a good one. Read through the docs; it's a class will worth familiarizing yourself with

Comment: Are you looking to scrape this information from another website? If so then Simple HTML DOM Parser is very simple to use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net and I use it for something similar

Comment: Found that DOMDocument says invalid HTML file, and gives errors - I guess the entire HTML code received is not valid HTML file. Also, LIBXML_NOERRORS flag does not seem to suppress errors as I thought it would. If it would help, the exact HTML for this example can be found here: https://enp2.tribalwars.net/public_report/70d3a2a55461e9eb09f543958b608304 but unfortunately, files could have various formats, for example this one: https://enp2.tribalwars.net/public_report/5216e0e16c9d3657f981ce7e3cb02580

Comment: @luke_mclachlan, that is exactly what I want to do - thanks for explaining it so simple. I will check out the link you've sent.

Comment: Are you using http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php or http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php to load the file?

Comment: @Terminus - using loadhtml.

Comment: @luke_mclachlan looks like your comment will get me the closest to an answer. Still trying to get some little niggle sorted out. If it works, please post your comment as an answer...

Comment: @luke_mclachlan - looks like this will work, thank you - please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it :-)

Comment: Will do, out enjoying a coffee at the moment. Pleasure to help, I like this script because it is easy to understand  (for a hobby coder like me), very flexible and lots of support both here on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: @luke_mclachlan I have evaluated another answer, and it was more efficient than yours. I have therefore accepted that. I will upvote yours if you eventually post it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example with `DOMDocument`:

```
$url = 'https://enp2.tribalwars.net/public_report/70d3a2a55461e9eb09f543958b608304';

// prevent warnings to be displayed
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

# lets find interesting nodes:

// td that contains all the needed informations (the nearest common ancestor in other words)
$rootNode = $xp->query('(//table[@class="vis"]/tr/td[./h4])[1]')->item(0);

// first h4 node that contains the date
$dateNode = $xp->query('(./h4)[1]', $rootNode)->item(0);

// following h3 node that contains the player name
$winnerNode = $xp->query('(./following-sibling::h3)[1]', $dateNode)->item(0);

$attackerNode = $xp->query('(./table[@id="attack_info_att"]/tr/th/a)[1]', $rootNode)->item(0);

# extract special values

$winner = preg_replace('~ has won$~', '', $winnerNode->nodeValue);

$attackerID = html_entity_decode($attackerNode->getAttribute('href'));
$attackerID = parse_url($attackerID, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($attackerID, $queryVars);
$attackerID = $queryVars['id'];

$result = [ 'date' => $dateNode->nodeValue,
            'winner' => $winner,
            'attacker' => $attackerNode->nodeValue,
            'attackerID' => $attackerID ];

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Very nice answer with example, thanks, but yours is very similar to the one in the comments, using simple_html_dom class. Luke answered first, and it works, so I will accept his answer once he posts it as an answer, but I will upvote yours too. Thanks for doing the effort!

Comment: @KobusMyburgh: The main difference is that simple_html_dom is slow and doesn't the features and the flexibility of the combo DOMDocument/DOMXPath that are build-in classes.

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte thank you - okay - I will try both, and if the speed difference is significant, I will accept yours. The purpose is to of course, keep SO as relevant as possible with quality answers, so I guess that's just fair.

Answer (score 0):

it wouldnt be pretty but could you use `strpos` to return the start and end position of the tags/content. Then use `substr` to return that portion of the string.

`string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`

`mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`

I would say that having to do it like this probably means there is something wrong with how your recieving the data/further up. I really odnt think it's going to be efficient to keep scanning the dom over and over.

Comment: Thank you, @atoms, it does not really have to be efficient, as it is low volume usage, and not automated. Users will enter the URL as shown in the original question, and it will be scraped on demand.

The content of the tags will vary in size, so are you suggesting something like getting the strpos of the end of the closing tag, and the strpos of the start of the next tag then substr() that if there is more than one word in there?

Comment: yeah I would guess that to work, however the example above is a lot cleaner, I would suggest going with that.